# Count instances of item

Tags: elm

For example the input

```
["a", "b", "b", "c", "a"]
```

would lead to the output

```
[("a", 2), ("b", 2), ("c", 1)]
```

I can't really think of  a functional way to do this in elm

Comment: What algorithm did you try? Where did you get blocked?

Comment: [https://ellie-app.com/cQrRJNzTgYga1](https://ellie-app.com/cQrRJNzTgYga1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using existing code is a great idea, but I think it also makes sense to see the concepts:

To solve the requirement, you traverse the list using a recursive function and build an intermediary data structure. In this case a dictionary because it fits well to counting the occurrences of a string.
Then after the list was traversed and all elements were counted, you transform it to the list of tuples.

Full code on https://ellie-app.com/cLBnWHSBj5ta1

```
gather : List comparable -> Dict comparable Int -> List ( comparable, Int )
gather list dict =
    case list of
        [] ->
            Dict.toList dict

        first :: rest ->
            let
                count =
                    case Dict.get first dict of
                        Just value ->
                            value + 1

                        Nothing ->
                            1
            in
            Dict.insert first count dict
                |> gather rest
```

Most people like to use [fold](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/core/latest/List#foldl) instead of `case`-ing on the list, the ellie example also contains that code.

But the approach is the same: Solve the trivial case first (empty list) and then recurse the function until you meet the trivial case.

Comment: Thanks for actually giving a way to do it functionally and not a sort of hack

Answer (score 3):

If you can use [List.Extra.gatherEquals](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-community/list-extra/latest/List-Extra#gatherEquals) then you can just map the result of that function to fit your needs:

```
import List.Extra
List.map (\(x, y) -> (x, 1 + List.length y)) (List.Extra.gatherEquals ["a", "b", "b", "c", "a"])
-- [("a",2),("b",2),("c",1)]
```